# Is there a means to keep track of commands executed on command line?

Tags: linux, logging, command-line

I wanted to know if there was some means of keeping track of every command executed on command line in a chronological manner along with the working directory where it was executed and the output of the command. Like putting all of this information for a session into a log file that you can go through later.

Comment: Is this just for your session or system-wide? If it is just your session, you can use `script`. See `man script` If it is system-wide, then `sudo` and `sudoreplay` will do what you want for privileged commands that require `sudo`, but for non-privileged commands I don't know of anything.

Answer (score 1):

The acct program allows the system administrators to know exactly what their users were doing on their command line.

This site: http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/howto-log-user-activity-using-process-accounting.html has a detailed description on how to enable it.